# Backspace erasing bash prompt only after typing characters

Tags: linux, bash, unix, redhat, prompt

New linux user here.

My bash prompt looks like this:

```
export PS1=$"\[\e[1;32m\d \t \e[1;33mฅ^\e[m\e[1;36mᵒ\e[m\e[1;33mﻌ\e[m\e[1;36mᵒ\e[m\e[1;33m^ฅ \e[1;35m\W\e[1;32m$\]"
```

(it's a kitty `ฅ^ᵒﻌᵒ^ฅ`)

Now that I've added the `]` to the end of the string, it no longer deletes my bash prompt characters when the prompt is empty. However, it does delete my bash prompt once I start typing a command and then press backspace.

Is there a way to prevent this, or is this just a bash thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\[...\]` indicates that the contained part does not take up any space in the prompt. So, they're to be used for the xterm control sequences (`\e[1;32m`, etc.), not the prompt text (`\d`, `\t`, etc.). Try something like:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;32m\]\d \t\[\e[1;33m\]ฅ^\[\e[m\e[1;36m\]ᵒ\[\e[m\e[1;33m\]ﻌ\[\e[m\e[1;36m\]ᵒ\[\e[m\e[1;33m\]^ฅ\[\e[1;35m\]\W\[\e[1;32m$\]'
```

If your entire prompt is wrapped in `\[...\]`, then bash thinks your prompt takes no space at all, and typing begins at the start of the line.

(You don't need to export `PS1`, by the way.)

Comment: Better explanation than mine +1

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks for clearing that up for me!