# bash in urxvt - backspacing on alrady typed character while reading variable

Tags: bash, command-line, user-input, urxvt

The intent is to put the cursor at some position on the screen (around the center of the screen), enter some initial text, and prompt the user to enter more text to be saved in a variable, while leaving him the normal `readline` line editing capabilities.

My initial attemp was to:

1. center the cursor vertically  `echo`/`printf`ing some whitespace,
2. center the cursor horizontally again through `echo`/`printf`,
3. issue `read -i "editable pre-text" -e answer`.

However I noticed the behavior described below, and crafted the following exemplifying two lines-code to demonstrate it.

When executing the following script

```
echo -n "______________"
read -e risp
```

as long as no input is typed, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is ineffective (and this is kind of the behavior I like, as the characters entered by `echo` before `read` cannot be deleted during `read`).

However, typing something (e.g. some text) and then deleting it (completely, up to and including the first typed character) with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, will result in the cursor to jump to the first colon of the terminal as soon as <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the first typed character.

In other words, as the script starts, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> does nothing, while <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd> will result in the cursort to jump to the first column of the terminal.

What is the reason for this behvaior, and how can I avoid it?

Given the title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359600/backspace-erasing-bash-prompt-only-after-typing-characters) I would expect it to be related to the present one, but I can't understand if it really is.

Comment: `read -p _________` ? Why do you use `-e`?

Comment: `read -e` activates readline for the user's input, it cannot delete the output of `echo`.

Comment: Added details to address the 1st comment. Concerning the 2nd comment, it looks like it somehow does, or at least has the same effect as it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you should use `read`'s `-p` option to print the prompt, rather than trying to set it up before the `read` command.

The `-e` option asks `read` to use the `readline` library to handle the input, allowing a wider range of line-editing characters. However, in order to implement these behaviours, `readline` needs to be able to redraw the current line, and that's not possible if there is anything on the current line when the read starts. It's not possible because Unix provides no mechanism for an application to look at what's being displayed on the console. So under some circumstances, `readline` will simply clear the line. Using the `-p` option allows `readline` to output the prompt, and it can then know what the line currently looks like.